# Как выбрать с помощью jQuery только один li, с условием выборки двух классов?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть следующие классы:

```
<li class="holiday_homes steel_structures"></li>
<li class="holiday_homes reinforced_concrete"></li>
<li class="holiday_homes reconstruction"></li>
```

Как выбрать с помощью jQuery, только один li, с условием выборки двух классов? К примеру, пробую так, не получается:

```
$('li').find('.holiday_homes, .steel_structures');
```

Comment: а где тут указывается, что выбирается первый?

Comment: извиняюсь, li - тэги не сразу отобразились

Comment: я вообще имел ввиду сам селектор: нет ни одного указания какой элемент выбирается

Comment: Мне надо выбрать всего один li с двумя классами. Я понимаю, что если бы класс был один, то к примеру можно было бы писать так: $('li .holiday_homes') . Но у меня два класса, и мне надо выбрать именно с помощью них.

Comment: стоит добавить в вопрос ожидаемый результат селектора, для данного набора. И уточнить по какому принципу выбирать. То ли _первый_, то ли _один_

Comment: Нет, мне не нужен только первый, это я к примеру написал. Мне нужен только один. Разница в этих li в том, что у них второй класс меняется, а первый holiday_homes у всех одинаков.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В селекторах jQuery применяется синтаксис аналогичный CSS таким образом выбор элементов с двумя классами будет выглядеть так

```
$('elementName.ClassName1.ClassName2')
```

Если нужно выбрать только первый, то применять функцию `first` описанную ниже, либо [`eq(0)`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/), который так же можно добавить в селектор.

**Важно:** Если есть уверенность, что элемент с этими двумя классами *только* один, либо все с такими классами, то никаких дополнительных манипуляций не нужно.

---

Есть множество способов, например метод [first](https://api.jquery.com/first/)

```
$( "li" ).first().css( "background-color", "red" );
```

Comment: Спасибо тебе. Помог. Вылетело из головы, что нужно классы писать вместе: $('.holiday_homes.reinforced_concrete'); , а я писал их раздельно.